# Can't seem to draw an image onto the canvas using functional react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, webrtc

I am trying to draw an image to the canvas in react with typescript functionally.

I try to draw the image onto the canvas however nothing is happening on the canvas and my console log returns `undefined` not sure why this happens. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
        function getCanvas() {
            const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.setAttribute('id', 'canv1');
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

            const imageObj1 = new Image();
            imageObj1.src = 'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/d7/b3/cf/d7b3cfe04c2dc44400547ea6ef94ba35.jpg';

            imageObj1.addEventListener('load', (e) => {
                const drawImage = (ctx as CanvasRenderingContext2D).drawImage(imageObj1, 33, 71, 104, 124, 21, 20, 87, 104);
                                // returns undefined
                console.log('REMOVE-ME',drawImage);
            });
                        // Nothing happens on the canvas
            return canvas;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code in isolation looks good...

The `undefined` is fine as return of drawImage, you can see that in the documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage#return_value

In your code the name of the function is `getCanvas` but you are doing `document.createElement('canvas')` I hope that object is injected into somehow.

I tested the image with those same parameters and it loads fine:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
ctx.fillRect(5, 5, 90, 10)

var image = new Image()
image.src = "https://i.pinimg.com/236x/d7/b3/cf/d7b3cfe04c2dc44400547ea6ef94ba35.jpg"
image.onload = imageLoaded

function imageLoaded() {
  ctx.drawImage(image, 33, 71, 104, 124, 21, 20, 87, 104)
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

To further troubleshoot your side try to draw something simpler like a small rectangle:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillRect
see if that shows, is the problem only with images or could it be the location of the canvas...